# Convert JSON Data into Excel File Download in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, excel, type-conversion

I have a AJAX POST Request fetching data back in form of a JSON Array.
I want to convert this received JSON Data into an Excel File (Not CSV) for download (on a button-click), pls help. The JSON Data might have blank values and missing fields for each JSON row.

I tried this in Client side using Javascript but not in Java server side in which case I will have to use @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) in the AJAX End-Point method, which is something I can try but think its complex.

a) AJAX Request code:

```
function fileUploadFunction() {

    var file = $('input[name="file"').get(0).files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    if(file.name != null) {
        document.getElementById("btnUpload").disabled = false;

        formData.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
            url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/rest/upload/upload",
            type : "POST",
            data : formData,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(response) {
                //Store result in Session and Enable Download button
                var cacheString = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
                console.log("-----------------> cacheString is: " + cacheString);
                if(cacheString != null && cacheString != "[]") {
                    document.getElementById("download").disabled = false;
                }
                var sessionresponse = sessionStorage.setItem("i98779", cacheString); 

                console.log("response is: " + response);
                console.log("cacheString is: " + cacheString);
                excelDownload(cacheString);
                //createTable(response);
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330520/how-to-export-json-object-into-excel-using-javascript-or-jquery

            },

            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });//ajax ends

    }//if ends

}//Function ends
```

b) JSON Sample data received from AJAX POST Request:

```
[
    {
    "entityid":2,
    "firstname":"George",
    "lastname":"Bush",
    "ssn":"",
    "city":"Houston",
    "state":"TX",
    "country":"USA",
    "zipcode":""
    },
    {
    "entityid": 8,
    "firstname": "Jim",
    "lastname": "Macron",
    "ssn": "888-88-8888",
    "city": "Paris",
    "state": "NY",
    "country": "France",
    "zipcode": "T789J"
    },
    {
    "entityid": 11,
    "firstname": "Angela",
    "lastname": "Merkel",
    "city": "Saxony",
    "zipcode": ""
    },
    {
    "entityid": 7,
    "firstname": "Donald",
    "lastname": "Trump",
    "ssn": "777-77-7777",
    "city": "Washington D.C.",
    "state": "DC",
    "country": "USA",
    "zipcode": "70000"
    }

]
```

Comment: Do u accept an answer producing Excel from Java back end?

Comment: Sure, that should be fine too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to produce an excel from the WebService (Resteasy Implementation), tested and fully working:

```
@POST
    @Path("/excelpost")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response downloadFilePost( ) throws IOException {

         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
            Object[][] datatypes = {
                    {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
                    {"int", "Primitive", 2},
                    {"float", "Primitive", 4},
                    {"double", "Primitive", 8},
                    {"char", "Primitive", 1},
                    {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
            };

            int rowNum = 0;
            System.out.println("Creating excel");

            for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                int colNum = 0;
                for (Object field : datatype) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                    if (field instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                    } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                    }
                }
            }

                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                workbook.write(outputStream);
                workbook.close();


            return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename='fileName.xlsx'")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                    .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600").entity( new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray() )).build();


    }
```

this is the maven dependency to manage Excel file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

You could easily add proper annotations and webparameter to manage file input from startin post of your service:

```
@POST
@Path("/excelpost")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadFilePost(MultipartFormDataInput input)
   .......
```

Let me know if it helps...

Comment: @Blackjack, thanks for your help, appreciate it, but getting error below:

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [restserver] in context with path [/restserver] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell cannot be cast to com.google.common.collect.Table$Cell] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell cannot be cast to com.google.common.collect.Table$Cell

Comment: Was asked to CAST as below:
        for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    ((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell) cell).setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    ((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell) cell).setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: This is because you are trying to put an com.google.common.collect.Table$Cell inside an Excel Cell  which cannot accept that value. You need to take out the value and put THAT value to excel cell object.

Comment: Ok, changed to below and getting file download but with Junk characters:         

for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Please post you implementation I don't understand what you're doing. Basically its the way you pass value to excel cell.

Comment: How is the outputstream created with no reference to excel, maybe this is the issue.

--------------> ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Will paste code separately, as its too long to add in Comments.

Comment: Posted code below ... thank you so much ... Just a FYI ... I am getting no file download. And the below 2 lines give Junk characters in console of Browser that I can see using Chrome ...                console.log("response is: " + response);
                console.log("cacheString is: " + cacheString);

Answer (score 0):

@Blackjack, below is the code ...

1) Function being called on click of a button. This has AJAX Call that passes an Excel file to a REST Endpoint function:

```
function fileUploadFunction() {

    var file = $('input[name="file"').get(0).files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    if(file.name != null) {
        document.getElementById("btnUpload").disabled = false;

        formData.append('file', file);
        $.ajax({
            url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/rest/upload/bulkSearch",
            type : "POST",
            data : formData,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(response) {
                //Store result in Session and Enable Download button
                var cacheString = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
                console.log("-----------------> cacheString is: " + cacheString);
                if(cacheString != null && cacheString != "[]") {
                    document.getElementById("download").disabled = false;
                }
                var sessionresponse = sessionStorage.setItem("i98779", cacheString); 

                console.log("response is: " + response);
                console.log("cacheString is: " + cacheString);
                //excelDownload(cacheString);
                //createTable(response);
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330520/how-to-export-json-object-into-excel-using-javascript-or-jquery

            },

            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });//ajax ends

    }//if ends

}//Function ends
```

2) REST End-Point function:

```
@POST 
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Path("/bulkSearch") 
public Response bulkSearch( 
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, 
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws IOException { 

    System.out.println("Entered uploadFile method");
    System.out.println("uploadedInputStream is: " + uploadedInputStream);
    System.out.println("fileDetail is: " + fileDetail.toString());

    String returnJSON = null;
    List<User> usersList = null;
    ObjectMapper uploadMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //System.out.println("File name is: " + fileDetail.getFileName());
    //System.out.println("File size is : " + fileDetail.getSize());
    //System.out.println("File size is : " + fileDetail.getType());

    // check if all form parameters are provided 
    if (uploadedInputStream == null || fileDetail == null) 
        return Response.status(400).entity("Invalid form data").build();

    System.out.println("Checked Input file is ok");

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
    Object[][] datatypes = {
            {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
            {"int", "Primitive", 2},
            {"float", "Primitive", 4},
            {"double", "Primitive", 8},
            {"char", "Primitive", 1},
            {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
    };

    int rowNum = 0;
    System.out.println("Creating excel");

    for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        int colNum = 0;
        for (Object field : datatype) {
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
            if (field instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) field);
            } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
            }
        }
    }

        System.out.println("For loop done");

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //-----> no reference to excel cells here
        System.out.println("outputstream done");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        System.out.println("workbook.write done");
        workbook.close();
        System.out.println("workbook closed");


    return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename='fileName.xlsx'")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600").entity( new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray() )).build();



}
```